# Increase EEPROM capacity and data lines

Tags: memory, eeprom, rom

**Question**: I need to increase the capacity and data lines of a EEPROM board using decoder and/or basic logic gates. The EEPROM is Hitachi HN58C1001. it is 128K by 8 bits. Task is to make it 1M by 32 bits.

My guess is to use decoder (3to8) and connect it to CE pins of 8 of this boards, I'll give me 1M of data but also 64 data lines, not 32...

What is the correct way to do this?

[image]

Comment: If you're using CE to control the chips then why do the buses need to be parallel?

Comment: This is how addresses are working usually - part of the address is decoded into the CE signals and the other part is connected to the address lines of the chips *in parallel*. Data will be connected in parallel too as CE is driving the chips which are off to be in high-Z outputs.

Comment: You just duplicate the thing 4 times and put them onto the data bus.

Comment: At minimum you need to decode your extra address high order address bits and CE, OE and WE if you write to them in-situ. If you are expanding the width to 32 bits then you need to ignore your least significant 2 bits of address (simple renumbering) when connecting in parallel.

Comment: Also when you say X by Y bits you mean X units with each unit being Y bit. So changing from 128K by 8 bit to 1M by 32 bit you and increasing capacity from 1Mbit to 32Mbit, which doesn't look like what you are trying to do. Please clarify your question further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing address space with data space.

You do indeed need to multiply your address space by 8, but you only need to multiply your data width by four.

As such you need a matrix of memory devices that is 8 rows by 4 columns. That is, 32 devices.

You are correct, you need to decode the upper three bits of the 1M address bus to select the appropriate row. Then feed each device across that row into the appropriate byte of the 32 bit data bus.

If the memory is byte addressable you will need to offset the address on the devices to ignore the bottom two bits. That is, feed address bus bit 2 to device A0... etc.

Also, make sure whatever is driving the address control and data lines has enough fan-out to drive all those devices in parallel. If not, you will need additional buffers in there with consequent timing delays.